# I can't get this script to work with folders containing spaces, how should i solve it?

Tags: bash, debugging, syntax-error

I cant get the following script to work whenever the path($1) contains one or more spaces. What should i change to make it work?

```
#!/bin/bash
ws=/tmp/$RANDOM && mkdir $ws && cd $ws
TRG=$1 && SRC=$1
if [ "$1" != "" ];then
    if [ "$3" != "" ];then
        if [ "$2" == "enc" ];then
            if [[ -d $1 ]];then
                mv $1 ./
                zip -rq "$(basename $1).zip" "$(basename $1)" 
                SRC="$ws/$(basename $1).zip"
            fi
            openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in $SRC -out $TRG -pass file:<( echo -n "$3" )
        elif [ "$2" == "dec" ];then
            mv $1 ./
            SRC="$ws/$(basename $1)"
            openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -salt -in $SRC -out $TRG -pass file:<( echo -n "$3" )
            if grep -q "PK" <<<"$(awk 'FNR == 1 { print; exit }' $TRG)"; then
                rm "$ws/$(basename $TRG)"
                mv "$TRG" "$ws/$(basename $TRG)"
                TRG="$ws/$TRG"
                mkdir "$1"
                unzip -o -qq "$(basename $TRG)" -d "$(cd $1 && cd .. && pwd)"
            fi
        else
            echo "Incorrect operation"
        fi
    elif [ "$2" == "" ];then
        echo "Password and mode is required"
    else
        echo "Password is required"
    fi
else
    echo "No path specificated"
fi
rm -rf $ws
```

I know that i need to add quotes but if i do that i think i will screw up some existent commands in the code...

Comment: Run your code though and http://www.shellcheck.net/ as it will properly solve your problem :-)

Comment: Also note that `$(basename "$1")` can be substituted with `${1##*/}`

Comment: @andlrc Thanks, I'll check that site out and use ${1##*/} instead of basename!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to quote variables inside `$(...)` too. If not this can lead to unexpected behaviour. So replace all `"$(basename $1)"` with `"$(basename "$1")"`. 
And also quote assignments `TRG="$1"`.

Then it should look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
ws=/tmp/$RANDOM && mkdir "$ws" && cd "$ws" || exit
TRG="$1" && SRC="$1"
if [ "$1" != "" ];then
    if [ "$3" != "" ];then
        if [ "$2" == "enc" ];then
            if [[ -d $1 ]];then
                mv "$1" ./
                zip -rq "$(basename "$1").zip" "$(basename "$1")" 
                SRC="$ws/$(basename "$1").zip"
            fi
            openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in "$SRC" -out "$TRG" -pass file:<( echo -n "$3" )
        elif [ "$2" == "dec" ];then
            mv "$1" ./
            SRC="$ws/$(basename "$1")"
            openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -salt -in "$SRC" -out "$TRG" -pass file:<( echo -n "$3" )
            if grep -q "PK" <<<"$(awk 'FNR == 1 { print; exit }' "$TRG")"; then
                rm "$ws/$(basename "$TRG")"
                mv "$TRG" "$ws/$(basename "$TRG")"
                TRG="$ws/$TRG"
                mkdir "$1"
                unzip -o -qq "$(basename "$TRG")" -d "$(cd "$1" && cd .. && pwd)"
            fi
        else
            echo "Incorrect operation"
        fi
    elif [ "$2" == "" ];then
        echo "Password and mode is required"
    else
        echo "Password is required"
    fi
else
    echo "No path specificated"
fi
rm -rf "$ws"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!